# Odoo display multiple wizards using tree view

Tags: treeview, action, formwizard, odoo-13, one2many

I have a form with a tree view. Each line has a button to open a wizard containing informations about the line.

This first wizard contains also a tree view and each line of it has a button to trigger the opening of another wizard (second one). But once i try to open it (second wizard using any line) the first one closes.

Any idea ?

Comment: the first wizard can return {"target": current or inline}

Comment: This opens the wizard in a new page. I want to stay in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by specifying the **tree_view_ref** attribute in the context and removed the button. In this way when i click on the line (not the button) i get a new wizard on the first one without hidding it

```
<field name="one2many_field" context="{'tree_view_ref': 'ref_to_second_wizard_id'}">
    <tree>...</tree>
</field>
```